# Problemas com LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout

Estou iniciando na aprendizagem sobre desenvolvimento android.Fazendo um curso básico do estudonauta.Ao chegar na aula sobre LinearLayout's a coisas desandaram.A ideia é inserir 1 LinearLayout(Geral) que suporta outros 2 LinearLayout's internos.Mas ao inserir componentes como textview, não é exibido na emulação.Fica tipo escondido.

Segue algumas fotos para desmontrar melhor o problema:

Como é para ser:
[image: Foto 1]
Desenvolvimento:
[image: Foto 2]
[image: Foto 3]
Obs:como pode observar ao inserir os componentes text view no Layout3(layoutResultado).Os componentes já não estão sendo exibidos.

Emulação:
[image: Foto 4]

Código XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconetopo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layoutGeral"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="649dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDados"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutResusltado"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema da exibição dos componente é divido aos tamanhos colocados nos mesmos.

1. Você colocou um tamanho fixo no layoutGeral o ideal é utilizar `layout_width="match_parent"` para pegar o espaço total na horizontal e `layout_height="wrap_content"` para pegar o tamanho necessário para atender a exibição dos itens que estão dentro dele.
2. No layoutDados e layoutResusltado você esta utilizando `layout_height="match_parent"` o match_parent vai pegar o tamanho total da tela, desta forma o layoutDados joga o layoutResusltado  para fora da exibição da tela, troque nos dois layouts para `layout_height="wrap_content"` e cada layout pegara apenas o espaço necessário para exibir seus itens.
3. No layoutGeral você colocou `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` isso faz com que o layoutGeral fique alinhado ao final da pagina, eu removi para que o layoutGeral venha logo após a imagem e o texto no topo, caso queira espaçar mais você pode utilizar o marginTop.

Exemplo corrigido:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/iconetopo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutGeral"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutDados"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutResusltado"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: O xml da pergunta não estava devidamente indentado, por isso não aparecia todo. Ele tem como layout principal um ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Eu acho que o ConstraintLayout deve ser o principal(como o ramaral citou).O professor Guanabara fez dessa forma:Imagem View e text view soltos na partes de cima(fixados pelas setas constrainslayout) e depois ele criou os linearLayouts embaixo.                                                          
   "Porem conforme o código XML que você passou na pergunta, seu layout esta com 3 objetos soltos um ImageView, um TextView e o LinearLayout."
 Qual seria o LinearLayout que você disse que está solto?Seria o LayoutGeral?       O app exibiu agora  os componentes.Mas está tudo um em cima do outro.

Comment: O ConstraintLayout não estava aparecendo na pergunta, vou editar a resposta.

Comment: É mesmo.Me desculpa.Só agora que percebi que faltava um trecho do código.Obrigado ramaral pela correção.

Comment: @Ronan corrigi a resposta, e atualizei xml de exemplo, testei ele aqui e funcionou.

Comment: @AlissonMarqui obrigado.Ajudou bastante.Fiquei um bom tempo batendo a cabeça para poder solucionar.Agora sim,o app está nos conformes e posso dar continuidade ao aprendizado.Muito obrigado!!!